# Grails object relationship where owned side doesn't have a reference back to its owner

Tags: grails

Why might you want to delcare a relationship in between two objects in Grails where the owned side DOES NOT have a reference to its owner (any scenarios where this might be appropriate or does it improve performance in any way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why might you want to delcare a relationship in between two objects in
>   Grails where the owned side DOES NOT have a reference to its owner...

You would want to declare a relationship like that if you had no use for the child to have a reference to its owner.  If you aren't going to use it and it doesn't do anything for you, don't declare one.  If you have scenarios where you have a reference to a child and you want to easily navigate from that back to the parent, then do declare one.

**EDIT**

The question is almost like asking "Why might you want to declare a domain class that doesn't have any String properties in it?".  You would do that if you didn't have any use for String properties.  Likewise, if the child doesn't have any use for a reference back to its parent, don't declare one.